# How can I design html like this?

Tags: html, css, forms

How can I design my div ("Personal Information" part) to look like the example below.

[image]

Comment: Try reading about some things called CSS and HTML

Comment: @Calum Such comment didn't help at all.

Comment: Hi, the question was closed so I can't answer. This is not the best way to do it as well, but, this is what I could think of: http://jsfiddle.net/BTJLB/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .personal_information label { display: inline-block; padding-right: 10px; text-align: right; width: 200px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="personal_information">
      <h1>Booking</h1>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input id="first_name" name="first_name" /><br />
        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input id="last_name" name="last_name" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Stacey. I've got it =)

Answer (score 3):

This probably is a `<fieldset>`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need to know. I knew it can be archived with html/css but I just didn't know how is it called.